# Running bootstrap on Total Least Squares Regression coefficent

Tags: r, regression, statistics-bootstrap

I ran a Total Least Squares regression with multiple predictors, but my code does not yield any p-values, etc. For the purposes of my paper, I need to assess the significance of the coefficients in the hope of bootstrapping to obtain percentile confidence intervals, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

I've tried the command boot(data, statistic, R), but I'm not sure what to input for data. The function I have is a regression using odregress command in pracma. I simply isolated a vector of my DV and a matrix with my IV values for the command.

```
X <- data.matrix(avgsubset1) # matrix of all preditors (IV)


Y <- as.vector(v$avgdatadelay.beh1)  #vector of DV


TLS <- odregress(X,Y); TLS


getRegr <- function(X, Y) {
bsFit <- odregress(X,Y)
as.numeric(coef(bsFit))
}


nR <- 1000
(bsRegr <- boot(data = ???, statistic=getRegr, R=nR))

boot.ci(bsRegr, conf=0.95, type="bca")$bca
```

Comment: Do not separate the data. The *full*  dataframe is what `boot` needs.

Comment: Are those two questions (p-values and boot)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to `boot` is not correct and nor is the boot statistic function.

```
library(pracma)
library(boot)

getRegr <- function(data, indices, DV = "avgdatadelay.beh1") {
  d <- data[indices, ]
  i_dv <- match(DV, names(d))
  X <- data.matrix(d[-i_dv])
  Y <- d[[i_dv]]
  bsFit <- odregress(X, Y)
  bsFit[["coeff"]]
}

set.seed(1234)

b <- boot(v, getRegr, R = 1000, DV = "avgdatadelay.beh1")

bad <- apply(b$t, 2, function(x) {
  which(is.infinite(x) | is.na(x) | is.nan(x))
})
i <- apply(bad, 1, unique)

b$t0
#[1]  9.1914957 -8.3566747 -0.2006832

if(NROW(bad)) {
  i <- apply(bad, 1, unique)
  colMeans(b$t[-i, ])
}else colMeans(b$t)
#[1] -2.700675e+13  2.384763e+13  1.489417e+12
```

**Data.**

The data is in the first example of the help page `?pracma::odregress`.

```
set.seed(2019)

x <- c(1.0, 0.6, 1.2, 1.4, 0.2)
y <- c(0.5, 0.3, 0.7, 1.0, 0.2)

v <- data.frame(avgdatadelay.beh1 = y, 
                x1 = x, 
                x2 = jitter(x))
```